Issues Connecting to MongoDB Atlas Using Mongoose in Node.js
I'm having trouble connecting my Node.js application to MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose. Here are the details of the issue and what I've tried so far:
Context:
MongoDB Atlas URI (sanitized): mongodb+srv://***:***@mycluster.gmoxw.mongodb.net/myTodoApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority
Node.js Version: v18.16.0
Mongoose Version: 7.x.x
MongoDB Atlas Cluster: I verified the connection works through MongoDB Compass.
Whitelist IP Address: My current IP is already whitelisted in MongoDB Atlas.
Error Received:
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Connecting to DB with URL: mongodb+srv://***:***@mycluster.gmoxw.mongodb.net/myTodoApp?
server running on PORT 3000
Failed to connect to db
node:internal/assert:14
    throw new ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION(message);
    ^

Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: This is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect usage of Node.js internals.
Please open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at assert (node:internal/assert:14:11)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1077:3)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1565:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:571:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  code: 'ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I also tried pinging the MongoDB Atlas cluster (mycluster.gmoxw.mongodb.net), but it always fails to find the host.
Steps I've Tried:
Added tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true to the connection string.
Verified IP Whitelisting is correct in MongoDB Atlas.
Confirmed the cluster works by connecting through MongoDB Compass.
Removed the deprecated options useNewUrlParser and useUnifiedTopology.
Checked that the Node.js and Mongoose versions are compatible.
Despite this, I keep getting the same error.
Questions:
What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?
Are there any additional configurations or options I should try to make the connection work?
Could this be related to my Node.js version or an SSL issue with MongoDB Atlas?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried connecting to MongoDB Atlas using the Mongoose library in my Node.js app. I expected the connection to succeed and allow my app to access the database. However, I keep getting an internal assertion error (ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION) and the connection fails. I also tried adding tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true and verified the cluster works in MongoDB Compass, but the issue persists.

do you have a network access setup correctly in your mongodb atlas?
